# create database routines function manually?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have an old database named `s3d_db` which i make backup from it through cPanel and Now i want to import this backup into a new database named `att_db` but when i do so phpmyAdmin only import tables and data and ask me super permission in order to import routines function so `is there any way that i can create this routines function manually and how i do that ?`

```
--
-- Dumping routines for database 's3d_db'
--
/*!50003 DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `get_sem_no` */;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_client      = @@character_set_client */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_results     = @@character_set_results */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_col_connection = @@collation_connection */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = utf8 */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = utf8 */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = utf8_general_ci */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_sql_mode       = @@sql_mode */ ;
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = '' */ ;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`username`@`localhost` FUNCTION `get_sem_no`(`time` time) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
DECLARE seminer_no INT DEFAULT FALSE;
SELECT semno INTO seminer_no FROM abs_ceminer_times WHERE time BETWEEN start_time AND end_time AND rest != 1;
RETURN seminer_no;
END ;;
DELIMITER ;
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = @saved_sql_mode */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = @saved_cs_client */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = @saved_cs_results */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = @saved_col_connection */ ;
/*!50003 DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `get_student_courses` */;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_client      = @@character_set_client */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_results     = @@character_set_results */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_col_connection = @@collation_connection */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = utf8 */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = utf8 */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = utf8_general_ci */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_sql_mode       = @@sql_mode */ ;
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = '' */ ;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`username`@`localhost` FUNCTION `get_student_courses`(`st_id` int) RETURNS text CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
  DECLARE course_id INT;
  DECLARE cid_string TEXT;
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE csr CURSOR FOR SELECT `cid` FROM `abs_student_courses` WHERE abs_student_courses.sid = st_id;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
  SET cid_string = "";
  OPEN csr;
  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH csr INTO course_id;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    SET cid_string = IF(cid_string != '',CONCAT(cid_string,",",course_id),course_id);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE csr;
  RETURN cid_string;
END ;;
DELIMITER ;
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = @saved_sql_mode */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = @saved_cs_client */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = @saved_cs_results */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = @saved_col_connection */ ;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2018-01-22  8:09:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the

```
DEFINER=`username`@`localhost`
```

clauses from the `CREATE` statements. Then it will create the routines with you as the creator, rather than copying the original creator. This doesn't require `SUPER` privileges.